# Where to put Datatables JS logic in laravel using laravel mix?

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, laravel-5.8, laravel-mix

I am new to all of this. I'm so sorry this weird question.

I am planning to use Yajra Datatables Package to show some dynamic tables in Laravel. I have Laravel Mix installed. Apperantly datatables needs to js logic to work like sending/getting stuff with ajax.

In [Laravel Mix Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#working-with-scripts) it says:

> Similar to combining stylesheets with mix.styles(), you may also
>   combine  and minify any number of JavaScript files with the scripts()
>   method

If i do this, will all of my pages that needs js will also include this particular Datatables logic for a particular table? Is this okay?

Ive mix installed but should i still use the "public/js" directory to include these type of scripts when they are needed?

**tldr;** Where should i put the js logic needed for datatables package in laravel?

**Edit:** Here is some example code. Where should i put this? I can just put in inside the related blade view but is it a good way of doing this?

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#MyDatatable').DataTable({
           processing: true,
           serverSide: true,
           ajax: "{{ url('users-all') }}",
           columns: [{ data: 'id', name: 'id' },
                    { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
                    { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
                    { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' }]});});
  </script>
```

Comment: Also abit unrelated but, should i use the npm version of datatables instead? Is it better, or maybe easier to use for newcomers?: https://www.npmjs.com/package/datatables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you do is correct but for reference:

1.First add `datatables` to your project via NPM or CDN. (Don't forget `jQuery` before `datatables`)

**CDN**

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">`

`<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>`

**NPM**

`npm install datatables --save-dev`

Import datatable in your project (For example if you are using Laravel deafult `app.js`)

```
import 'datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css';
import 'datatables';
```

2.Then You have multiple option but you can add something like `stack('scripts')` in your layout file and include your script in your blade view.

For example: 
`master.blade.php` (Example layout)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
@yield('content')
@stack('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

`dashbboard.blade.php` (Example page)

```php
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<h1>My Awesome Tables</h1>
<div id="MyDatatable"></div>
@endsection

@push('scripts')
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#MyDatatable').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ url('users-all') }}",
            columns: [{data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
                {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'}]
        });
    });
@endpush
```

We should use this approach because you use `{{ url('users-all') }}` so it must be in blade so you can print it. other wise you can use it on your `app.js` and add your url endpoint in other way.

Comment: Stacks looks nice. Thank you alot. btw should i use the api auth stuff in laravel docs for using ajax?

Comment: Your welcome. If it's useful please consider answer as accepted. Yes you should use respective CSRF token. more info at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: I was talking about this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication
You give users an api_token and expect it during api calls? you also your api routing instead of the web routing? Are these really necessary? There is also a hashed version which needs its additional page to initialize and refresh the hashed token. I really don't understand it. Where do you even save that token in the client side? cookie?

Comment: Well in this case i dont know how to do it sorry.